# make plugin to embed video player on wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, devise

I want from anyone to do plugin WordPress that add my special link video to post.
I have this page that is work good and I want to change it to do as plugin wordpress.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ace Stream</title>

<style type="text/css">
* {
    font-family: Arial;
}
body {
    background-color: #222
}
.modal {
    background-color:#fff; 
    display:none; 
    width: 500px; 
    padding:15px; 
    text-align:left; 
    border:2px solid #333; 
    font-size: 12px;
    
    opacity:0.8;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #ccc; 
}

.modal input {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.button-long {
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent url(http://static.torrentstream.org/htmlplayer/img/sprite-player-black.png) no-repeat 100% -129px;
    height: 27px;
    line-height: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 17px;
    top: -3px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    width: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.button-long b {
    background: transparent url(http://static.torrentstream.org/htmlplayer/img/sprite-player-black.png) no-repeat -579px -129px;
    height: 27px;
    width: 17px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -17px;
}

</style>

<!-- black style -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.torrentstream.org/jsapi/css/ts-controls-black.css" />

<!-- api files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.torrentstream.org/jsapi/js/lib/ts/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.torrentstream.org/jsapi/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.torrentstream.org/jsapi/js/lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.torrentstream.org/jsapi/js/lib/jquery/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.torrentstream.org/jsapi/js/lib/jquery/jquery.jscrollpane.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.torrentstream.org/jsapi/js/lib/jquery/jquery.scrollText.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.torrentstream.org/jsapi/js/lib/jquery/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.torrentstream.org/jsapi/js/lib/cufon/cufon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.torrentstream.org/jsapi/js/lib/cufon/a_LCDNova_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.torrentstream.org/jsapi/js/lib/ts/player.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.torrentstream.org/jsapi/js/lib/ts/controls.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
    var useInternalControls = true;
    
    var controls = new TorrentStream.Controls("tsplayer", {
            style: useInternalControls ? "internal" : "ts-black",
            debug: true
    });
    
    try {
        var player = new TorrentStream.Player(controls.getPluginContainer(), {
                debug: true,
                useInternalControls: useInternalControls,
                bgColor: "#000000",
                fontColor: "#ffffff",
                onLoad: function() {
                    this.registerEventHandler(controls);
                    controls.attachPlayer(this);
                    try {
                        var p = this;
                        this.loadPlayer("f47d788d767eaec24320f265e9c0cec5307d94ab", {autoplay: true});
                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        console.log("init: " + e);
                    }
                }
        });
    }
    catch(e) {
        controls.onSystemMessage(e);
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="player_container" style="background-color: #000; width: 800px; height: 483px; margin: 0 auto 0 auto;">
        <div id="tsplayer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; color: #fff; text-align: center;">
            <div style="padding-top: 232px; background-color: #000000;">Подождите, идет загрузка плеера...</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    init();
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>​
```

when add these code in this page to my post on wordpress is work good but it is difficult to add all this codes with all new posts

just my changeable with all my new post is this "f47d788d767eaec24320f265e9c0cec5307d94ab"

I want the plugin to use above codes when add [/tv_vid]link[/tv_vid] to my post
for example

[/tv_vid]f47d788d767eaec24320f265e9c0cec5307d94ab[/tv_vid]

Also I want the height and width of player suitable with browsers and mobile devises

I don't know any programming language.
please help me and thank you for all.

Comment: help me please I need the plugin